# Size of an orbit

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X=Z \pmod 5$ and suppose that $G$ is the cyclic group of permutations of $X$ generated by the permutation $\pi$ defined by the rule $\pi(x)=2x$.

How would I figure the elements of $G$ in cycle notation and determine the orbits of $G$ on $X$.

Comment: The problem is simple enough to do the direct computation! $X$ has only $5$ elements.

Comment: Right, but how do you do the direct computation??

Comment: Well $G$ is just multiplication by $2^{n}$. Think about the definition of the orbit that contains $x = \{gx : g \in G\}$.

Comment: When doing the cycle notation, the important point is that every congruence class modulo 5 contains a power of 2. Hence $\pi$ is a 4-cycle. Just calculate the first four powers of 2, reduce mod 5, and you have the cycle.

Comment: @peoplepower: The class of $0$ doesn't contain a power of $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbits: $\{0\}$, $\{1, 2, 4, 8 = 3\}$.

(Just multiply each element of $\mathbb{Z}/5$ by $2$, the cycle notation should be suggestive by this as well.)